# Синтаксическая ошибка со вторым else,помогите!!! не могу понять

Tags: javascript

```
<script>

   function max_number (x, y, z)
   {
      if((x > y) && (x > z)) {
          alert(x); 
      }
      else { 
             if(y > z);
             {
                alert(y);
             }
             else {
                    alert(z);
             }
      }
   }

   max_number(4, 8, 3);

</script>
```

Comment: Заметка на будущее: количество восклицательных знаков не повышает ваши шансы получить ответ. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/93/181472

Answer (score 3):

уберите точку с запятой после if(y > z) и будет вам счастье. И да, слово n**u**mber пишется через **u**

Answer (score 2):

Пользуйтесь { } этими скобками, после if или else.